# How to detect number of fingers being used?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, touch

I'm making a game using Libgdx, I need to know if the user is using two fingers and if they are placed in the correct position. One finger should be on the right side of the screen and the other in the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the easiest solution **without using any listeners** is to just iterate over some count of pointers and calling simple `Gdx.input.isTouched()` - you have to set some "maximum pointers count" but hey - peoples usually has only 20 fingers :)

```
    final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_POINTERS = 20;
    int pointers = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_POINTERS; i++)
    {  
        if( Gdx.input.isTouched(i) ) pointers++;
    }

    System.out.println( pointers );
```

due to reference:

> Whether the screen is currently touched by the pointer with the given index. Pointers are indexed from 0 to n. The pointer id identifies the order in which the fingers went down on the screen, e.g. 0 is the first finger, 1 is the second and so on. When two fingers are touched down and the first one is lifted the second one keeps its index. If another finger is placed on the touch screen the first free index will be used.

you can also easily the position of touching pointer by using `Gdx.input.getX()` and `Gdx.input.getY()` like

```
    final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_POINTERS = 20;
    int pointers = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_POINTERS; i++)
    {  
        if( Gdx.input.isTouched(i) )
        {
            x = Gdx.input.getX(i);
            y = Gdx.input.getY(i)
        }
    }
```

and then you can for example put it into array

Comment: yup - look into method reference I've attached in the answer (orange block of text)

Comment: what if I wan't to implement InputListerner, the touchdown() method has a pointer parameter, how do I use that pointer variable to select what pointer/finger to use.

Answer (score 1):

> How to detect number of fingers being used?

You can do it with [`MotionEvent`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerCount%28%29) with `getPointerCount()`

You can detect how many fingers are on the screen doing this :

```
int PointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
```

> I need to know if the user is using two fingers and if they are placed in the correct position

You can get the X,Y and compare it.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   int x = event.getX();
   int y = event.getY();
   return true;
}
```

For more information you can check [`MotionEvent Documentation`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) so you can get there what you want.

Comment: x and y will get the coordinate of the finger, how about the second finger? the fingers should be on screen at the same time. I mean how do I get the coordinates of both fingers if they are touching the screen at the same time

Comment: Also I'm using libgdx and I cant use MotionEvent class,

Answer (score 1):

Both `GestureListener` and `InputProcessor` have the `touchDown` method. This has the x and y value for each finger on the screen (pointer). Implement either one of these and you can override the touchdown to suit your needs. [This](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/24/LibGDX-Tutorial-5-Handling-Input-Touch-and-gestures.aspx) is a great tutorial to start with. Hope this helps.